# C++/Qt Notification when sysfs attribute changed

Tags: c++, qt

I have a embedded system someone wrote a kernel module about can plug detection for. I am by no means even a beginner in writing kernel modules but from I what I know from the "documentation" of the module and the rough flow of it I know it watches for an interupt its has requested using `request_irq` does some debouncing and sets a sysfs attribute file according to it:

```
static ssize_t v_detect_show(struct device *dev, struct device_attribute *attr, char *buf)
{
    /*
    struct platform_device *pdev = to_platform_device(dev);
    struct can_detection_config* config = platform_get_drvdata(pdev);
    */
    struct can_detection_config* config = dev_get_drvdata(dev);

    if (gpiod_get_value_cansleep(config->detect_gpio))
        strcpy(buf, "plugged\n");
    else
        strcpy(buf, "unplugged\n");

    return strlen(buf);
}
static DEVICE_ATTR_RO(v_detect);
```

I know that this somehow ends up in the file `/sys/bus/platform/devices/can-detect/v_detect` so its a sysfs attribute. My question is how can I monitor the state change of the file without doing polling in my Qt/C++ application. I have tried to use a `QFileSystemWatcher` but looking at the output of `state v_detect` before and after the unplugging the modified date stays the same. Also tried using a `QSocketNotifier` to check for changes on the file descriptor:
`QSocketNotifier notifier(v_detect.handle(), QSocketNotifier::Read);`
But that thing is just firing non stop and is clogging up my event queue.

Any idea on how to achieve this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `QSocketNotifier::Read` by `QSocketNotifier::Exception`, and then when the signal is emitted, perform **readAll()**.